# use jquery to echo value from text box

Tags: php, jquery

I am attempting to echo out the value after a text box has been filled in.

```
<input name="cron" type="textbox" placeholder=" Please insert a valid command in cron time format" class="required" />
```

The value of this textbox will then need to go into my cron_parser function and will echo out with $next_time

```
$cron_parser = new cron_parser($cron);
$next_time = $cron_parser->next_runtime();
```

Essentially after the text box is filled in, I want the following result to be echo'd out on the screen and update if the text box is changed.

```
<div class="alert success">
<span class="icon"></span><strong>Is this correct?</strong>
Your backup will run next at <?php echo $next_time ?>
</div>
```

Comment: [What are the difference between server-side and client-side programming?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

Comment: You will probably need to make an AJAX call to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, to retrieve the value in the text box you can use jQuery as below

```
val = $('input[value="cron"]').val();
```

You can not just `echo` out the stuff at the client-side(after the page has been loaded) instead you can `alert(val);` But If really wanna pass the value to server-side(PHP side) you can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

[Client-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting)

[Server-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)

[Difference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)